# Null reference on local variable unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I have an issue with Null Reference on local variable that set by var argument inside `start()` method

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using K3DBHandler;

public class Splash : MonoBehaviour {
    private int jmlUser;
    private DataService ds = new DataService("dbK3.sqlite");

    void Start()
    {
       var user = ds.CekUser();
        Hitung(user);
        if (jmlUser == 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(ToLogin());
        }
        else
        {
            StartCoroutine(ToHome());
        }
    }

  IEnumerator ToHome()
  {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Home");
  }

    IEnumerator ToLogin()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Login");
    }
    private void Hitung(IEnumerable<User> UserCount)
    {
        var c = 0;
        foreach (var a in UserCount)
        {
            c++;
        }
        jmlUser = c;
    }
}
```

This code work well in Unity Editor but when I build it to Android, I got error like this:
[image: Null Reference Exception]

Please help me.

*Note: I use Unity 2017.3.1f1

Comment: If you double-click on that error from the Editor, it will take you to the line of code that is causing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity is telling you that one of the things in the Start method doesn't exist.

I have organized your code, so it will be easier to detect this object.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using K3DBHandler;

public class Splash : MonoBehaviour {
    private int jmlUser = 0;
    private DataService ds = null;

    void Start()
    {
       ds = new DataService("dbK3.sqlite");
       var user = ds.CekUser();
       Hitung(user);
       if (jmlUser == 0) StartCoroutine(ToLogin());
       else StartCoroutine(ToHome());
    }

    IEnumerator ToHome()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Home");
    }

    IEnumerator ToLogin()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Login");
    }

    private void Hitung(IEnumerable<User> UserCount)
    {
        int c = 0;
        foreach (var a in UserCount) c++;
        jmlUser = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Hector, but the error still exist

Comment: @HendriTriwanto Let's see, I'll try to help you solve it

Comment: @HendriTriwanto Do you use Twitter?

Comment: I do, @hendritriwanto_ is mine

Comment: This: https://twitter.com/hendritriwanto_ ?

Comment: Yes it is, thank you for your help Hector

Comment: Ok, follow me and we can start @hectorm432867